# How can I implement custom text to speech in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, text-to-speech

I want to add text to speech in my application, I´m using now TextToSpeech library, but I saw, that it is difficult to choose the voices and languages using this library, because some devices will have installed these specific voices and languages, and some of them not, and I don´t want to let the user download this data by himself, I want the application to do it which I think that is not possible.

So is there a way to create my custom TextToSpeach in my application? any references to do this?

Thank you all!